# Calculate revenues for each month by total revenues in r

Tags: r

Let’s say a consultancy releases the total revenues of firm A and B in region alpha and beta monthly, the data may look like:

```
# generate data

foo <- expand.grid(month = 1:3, region = c("alpha", "beta"), firm = c("A", "B"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
foo <- foo[order(foo$month, foo$region),]
rownames(foo) <- 1:nrow(foo)
foo <- foo[c(-1,-6),]
revenue <- c(1.5, 2, 2.1, 1.2, 3, 5.5, 3.2, 5, 5, 6)
foo <- cbind(foo, revenue)
foo

##    month region firm revenue
## 2      1  alpha    B     1.5
## 3      1   beta    A     2.0
## 4      1   beta    B     2.1
## 5      2  alpha    A     1.2
## 7      2   beta    A     3.0
## 8      2   beta    B     5.5
## 9      3  alpha    A     3.2
## 10     3  alpha    B     5.0
## 11     3   beta    A     5.0
## 12     3   beta    B     6.0
```

what I want to do is calculate revenues in each month. But I cannot handle all of these situations：

1. In January, revenues for this month is total revenues;
2. For new branch, the month it first appears acts like January for others;
3. And some data will lost, the next month revenue should be NA.

Basically, the result is:

```
result <- c(1.5, 2, 2.1, 1.2, 1, 3.4, 2, NA, 2, 0.5)
res <- cbind(foo, result)
res

##    month region firm revenue result
## 2      1  alpha    B     1.5    1.5
## 3      1   beta    A     2.0    2.0
## 4      1   beta    B     2.1    2.1
## 5      2  alpha    A     1.2    1.2  ## a new branch launched by A at alpha in Feb.
## 7      2   beta    A     3.0    1.0
## 8      2   beta    B     5.5    3.4
## 9      3  alpha    A     3.2    2.0
## 10     3  alpha    B     5.0     NA  ## the data of B at alpha in Feb. is missing
## 11     3   beta    A     5.0    2.0
## 12     3   beta    B     6.0    0.5
```

Thanks in advance~

Comment: I am thoroughly confused by your question. Please rephrase as to what you are seeking. Remember we are not in your head and don't understand the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you are looking for, but maybe this will be helpful. I assume that `revenue` is total/cumulative for each firm/region combination.

First, I would note the first appearance of revenue (new branch, one of your rules).

```
foo <- foo %>%
  group_by(region, firm) %>%
  mutate(first = first(month)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Then, would expand to get combinations of `firm/region` and fill with `NA`, and join back to your data frame. You can group by `region` and `firm` and set `result` to `revenue` if month is January (1). Otherwise, set to difference from last `revenue`.

Since new branch is to be treated like January, change `result` to `revenue` if the month is the `first` month and `result` was `NA`.

```
foo %>%
  expand(firm, nesting(region, month)) %>%
  left_join(foo) %>%
  group_by(region, firm) %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse(month == 1, revenue, revenue-lag(revenue))) %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse((is.na(result)) & (month == first), revenue, result)) %>%
  drop_na(revenue) %>%
  select(-first) %>%
  arrange(month, region)

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   region, firm [4]
   firm  region month revenue result
   <chr> <chr>  <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 B     alpha      1     1.5    1.5
 2 A     beta       1     2      2  
 3 B     beta       1     2.1    2.1
 4 A     alpha      2     1.2    1.2
 5 A     beta       2     3      1  
 6 B     beta       2     5.5    3.4
 7 A     alpha      3     3.2    2  
 8 B     alpha      3     5     NA  
 9 A     beta       3     5      2  
10 B     beta       3     6      0.5
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my english, but this is almost what I want. Thanks～